# 4 questions error after selecting free space for ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, ssd, error-handling

I have Sony Vaio VPCZ1 with 128 ssd drive , it's drive is combination of 2 64 ssd drive(Tooshiba). When i want to install ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 7 , after I select empty disk spaces for installation, ubuntu errors with just 4 questions in double quotation ("????").
I installed ubuntu on other lap tops without any problem, but this one...
I appreciate your answers in advance.